# Is it possible to specify parameters which go into the post body with blueprint?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I'd like to be able to document the parameters as if they were URL parameters, since I like how that bit of documentation renders a handy table. However, in my API, I would like those paremeters to plug into the JSON body rather than the URL. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [dedicated syntax](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/25) for describing, discussing (and thus also validating) message-body is in the making.

It will be based on the [Markdown Syntax for Object Notation](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson), similar to the actual URI Parameters description syntax  (eventually these two should converge).

Also see related [How to specify an optional element for a json request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734103/how-to-specify-an-optional-element-for-a-json-request-object) and [Is it possible to document what JSON response fields are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043514/apiary-is-it-possible-to-document-what-json-response-fields-are) questions.